# Empty array in smarter_csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I am using Ruby 2.1.1 and the gem [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) version 1.0.17. I am trying to get a simple example to work but keep getting an empty array. Any hints on what I am doing wrong.

```
2.1.1 :006 > f = File.open("/Users/diasks2/test.csv", "rb")

2.1.1 :007 > f.read
 => "source_language,target_language\rhello,hola\rlibrary,biblioteca"

2.1.1 :008 > require 'smarter_csv'
 => true 
2.1.1 :009 > data = SmarterCSV.process("/Users/diasks2/test.csv")
 => []
```

Comment: why not built in `CSV` lib ?

Comment: I have it working using the CSV lib but I wanted to check out how this gem performs parsing large files

Comment: try `data = SmarterCSV.process("/Users/diasks2/test.csv", row_sep: "\r")`

Comment: @UriAgassi that worked. If you put that as an answer I will accept it. I don't understand why row_sep is needed though. The examples in the README show a simple example working without it. Any insight into the why would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
data = SmarterCSV.process("/Users/diasks2/test.csv", row_sep: "\r")
```

When not indicating `row_sep`, `smarter_csv` will use the system new line separator which is `"\r\n"` for windows machines, and `"\r"` for unix machines. Your file has `"\r"` to separate the lines, so you need to explicitly indicate this.

---

**Edit** - apparently there is a feature for `smarter_csv` to *guess* the row separator - if you use the following:

```
data = SmarterCSV.process("/Users/diasks2/test.csv", row_sep: :auto)
```

The gem should identify file with lines ending with `\n`, `\r\n`, or `\r` and parse them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any setting to accept both types of files? I don't know beforehand which type (\r or \r\n) a user might upload.